# What kind of connector is this? 5 pin,looks like telephone connector

Tags: connector, hardware

Working on integrating this into my project,could rewire it into another type of five pin connector, but it would be way easier to get it connector that fits properly as
I have a lot of devices that use this plug. This is a pressure transducer by Edward's life sciences . [image: / 1]

My goal:
Normally, this transducer connects into a monitor on the wall to show a patient's blood pressure. The wall monitor itself does not log any data, it just displays it. What I'd like to do is catch the signal from the transducer , split it , send some to an Arduino which can log the data, and send the other portion to the wall monitor.

[image]

Comment: Edwards' website gives PX1800 as  the matching cable (you have to lie and say you are a doctor)

Comment: what does your goal have to do with the question?

Answer (score 2):

I think that's a proprietary connector.  The Matching cable is part number PX1800.
These are available from Edwards if you can convince them you're a doctor, but also they are sold on E-bay etc.

[image]

I have no idea what the connector on the other end of the cable is. There are 11 pins because the cables are available with up-to 3 input ends.